# Would a parser for this left-recursive grammar require infinite input?

Tags: formal-languages, parsers, left-recursion

I am considering this left recursive language grammar production rule:

```
Expr = Expr, "a" ;
```

As a production rule, I believe that this can be used to produce an infinite sequence of `aaa` by describing the rule like this:

> Given a non-terminal `Expr`, expand it to `Expr` followed directly by the literal `a`.
>
> Example: if `Expr` is initially `b`, it may be expanded to `ba`. `Expr` is now `ba`, and may be expanded again producing `baa` and this process repeats infinitely to produce `ba`, `baa`, `baaa`, and so on.

I have tried to visualize this grammar as follows:

[image: grammar production visualized]

I believe the grammar cannot terminate in its production, as it requires infinite recursion (in theory.)

Given that this is a valid production rule, I would believe that it is possible this grammar could also then be used as the definition to write a parser. I would describe that parser as:

> It accepts any sequence of non-terminals (the `Expr`) followed by an infinite sequence of `a`.

However, what is not clear to me is if a parser for this language would *require* an infinite sequence of `a` or if a finite sequence of `a` would be admissible: would `baa` *actually* be a valid input, or would a theoretical machine parser for this effectively produce an error saying:

```
baa
   ^ found termination, expected "a"
```

Appreciate any guidance you can provide me in thinking about this problem.

Comment: I assume that you are talking about a grammar that consists only of this rule (otherwise the question is unclear. I also don't understand where `"b"` comes from if this is the only rule in your grammar). This grammar corresponds to an empty language: there is no string $s$ (must be a finite sequence of terminals, [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#Some_mathematical_constructs_regarding_formal_grammars)) which can be derived from this grammar. Any reasonable parser generator should be able to detect it, and therefore the resulting parser will simply reject any string.

Comment: "I assume that you are talking about a grammar that consists only of this rule" Yes.

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you for the explanation and definition of a grammar link. Based on that and your comment, my understanding is that you are effectively saying that my example grammar does not have a starting symbol  (in the definition) and is therefor invalid according to the definition. I am not sure I understand why a reasonable parser would "simply reject any string" though instead of "produce an error stating the grammar is invalid" then? Is there precedence for  how parsers should handle grammars with a missing ?

Comment: Also, if you want to submit what you said as an answer I will mark it as such.

Comment: In practice, Iit’s up to parser what to do with incorrect strings. If the string is correct, a parser will build a syntax tree (maybe implicitly). If it’s not correct, it may try to recover a close correct string, print some kind of error, throw exception, etc. In case of empty language,   I would print an error during parser generation.

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar captures the empty language. To see this, you need to use the definition of a language described by a context-free grammar.

A context-free grammar is a tuple $(T,N,S,P)$, where $T$ is the set of terminals (a non-empty finite set), $N$ is the set of nonterminals (a non-empty finite set disjoint from $T$), $S \in N$ is the starting symbol, and $P$ is a collection of productions $A \to \alpha$, where $A \in N$ and $\beta \in (N \cup T)^*$.

In your case, $T = \{a\}$, $N = \{\mathrm{Expr}\}$, $S = \mathrm{Expr}$ (you are not stating this explicitly, but this is the only choice), and $P$ consists of the single rule $\mathrm{Expr} \to \mathrm{Expr} \, a$.

We say that $\beta$ produces $\gamma$ in one step, in symbols $\beta \Rightarrow \gamma$, if there exists a production $A \to \alpha \in P$ and two strings $\lambda,\mu \in (N \cup T)^*$ such that $\beta = \lambda A \mu$ and $\gamma = \lambda \alpha \mu$.

We say that $\beta$ produces $\gamma$, in symbols $\beta \Rightarrow^* \gamma$, if either $\gamma = \beta$, or $\beta \Rightarrow \delta \Rightarrow^* \gamma$ for some $\delta \in (N \cup T)^*$. This is the reflexive-transitive closure of $\Rightarrow$.

Finally, the language produced by the grammar is $\{ w \in T^* : S \Rightarrow^* w \}$.

In your case, a simple induction shows that $\mathrm{Expr} \Rightarrow^* \alpha$ iff $\alpha = \mathrm{Expr} \, a^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\mathrm{Expr} \, a^n \notin T^*$, we conclude that the language produced by your grammar is the empty language.